# How long would it take the Boeing 787 to go around the world?

Tags: flight-planning, boeing-787

How long would it take the B787 to complete a full trip around the world and how many times would they have to refuel in that trip?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "going around the world"? Great circle distance around the equator or what?

Comment: There are several definition of [circumnavigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumnavigation). You should edit your question to make it more specific. For example, make at least 40000km, land at your forst take-oof airport, pass through all meridians,....

Comment: Its not so simple, that type of flight would have to plan its refueling stops for airports that could handle that type of aircraft. It wouldn't fly in a straight line. You could just divide out the range by the fuel it could carry and get an X miles per gallon and Y segments, but it will be more.

Comment: Even in a no wind situation the earth is NOT a sphere it is wider at the equator than it is along the meridian, this will have a tangible effect on the outcome, which way is this plane going?

Comment: [Related question on astronomy, with Jupiter instead of Earth](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/17859)... in case that helps clarify what the question is asking for.

Comment: @fooot, This [one](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14874/why-arent-people-going-to-the-moon-any-more) and its comments may be of interest too.

Comment: [This question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16307/698) talks about circumnavigation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you departed from an airport near the equator and flew around the world with an average ground speed of 480 knots it would take about 45 hours plus the time needed for 2 fuel stops.

[Great Circle Mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=N00w90-n00e030-n00e150-n00w090&MS=wls&DU=mi&SG=480&SU=kts)

[image]